# Can jsoup return the location of a element returned by the outerHtml method?

Tags: jsoup

Is there a way to know the exact position of an element in the source code returned by the outerHml method of a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. After the parsing phase, the source position is not tracked in the DOM, so an element does not contain this information.

What are you looking to implement? There may be another way to do it.

Comment: I want to detect elements on the DOM and then highlight them in a source code viewer.

Comment: In that, rather than trying to stitch an element back to the original source, I'd be inclined to traverse the parsed DOM and print that out, and highlight the selected nodes (using an equality check). Look at the Element#html() implementation for an example of traversal.

Comment: In fact, that's what I already do, but the idea is to provide both representations. I've implemented a not elegant locator mechanism but I'm facing problems due to the way the html is rendered by the  outerHtml method. For a reason that I ignore, a unique line can contains one or several html tags.

Comment: OK. You may need to make a fork then, and extend Node to include start/stop position, and Tokeniser to set those when it sees start and end tags.

Comment: OK, keep in touch if I'm facing other problems.

Comment: BTW, let's consider this snippet.  
`<iframe title="Video" class=youtube-player autoplay=1 type=text/html width=380 "288" height=250 "214" src="http://www.video.com/" </iframe>`.  
How to avoid the outerHmtl method to render this?    
`<iframe class="youtube-player" width="380" height="250"  src="http://www.video.com/" "214"="" "288"="" type="text/html" autoplay="1" title="Video">`.  
where "288" and "214" as seen as empty attributes ?

Comment: [We're going outside of the scope of the question; this might not be the best location for the discussion.] I don't know logically how else you would parse those -- in html they are value-less attribute names.

Comment: @koj, have you decided to fork Jsoup, or did you find another solution?

Comment: I made a fork of Jsoup that tracks the source positions of all elements. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/tvogels/jsoup).